# mount existing 2 partition windows from 6 TB HDD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I'm new on Ubuntu. How to mount existing 2 partition windows from 6 TB HDD on Ubuntu? and I don't want to lose this data in recreating partitions and directories. Here is list drive, 6TB on sda.

my setup is:
1 SSD, and 1 6TB HDD (split in to 2 partition), my win 7 and ubuntu 16.04 installed on SSD, currently my problem is, my 2 partition didn't show up in ubuntu, but the OS partition from SSD is fine.

my sda only showup in terminal like this

```
Device      Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1      34        2081        2048    1M Microsoft LDM metadata
/dev/sda2    2082      262177      260096  127M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3  262178 11721045134 11720782957  5,5T Microsoft LDM data
```

lsblk -f

```
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                      
├─sda1                                                   
├─sda2                                                   
└─sda3                                                   
sdb                                                      
├─sdb1 vfat         6C61-C79A                            
├─sdb2                                                   
├─sdb3 ntfs         A80E6A3A0E6A0224                     /media/fredy/A80E6A3A0E
├─sdb4 ext4         41dc0ef2-12f2-40dd-8082-689bb5728e95 /
├─sdb5 swap         e191a70a-af71-44a0-9aaa-f5bb464a2233 [SWAP]
└─sdb6
```

Any guide or help?

Thank you

Here is my terminal snapshot if I type `sudo fdsik -l /dev/sdb`:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 223,6 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 157236A8-0CCA-49D3-BED0-23C3204E689C

Device         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1       2048    206847    204800  100M EFI System
/dev/sdb2     206848    468991    262144  128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb3     468992 417660927 417191936  199G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb4  417660928 456722431  39061504 18,6G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb5  456722432 468852735  12130304  5,8G Linux swap
/dev/sdb6  468852736 468860927      8192    4M BIOS boot
```

cat /etc/fstab

```
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5). 
# # <file system> <mount point> <type> <options> <dump> <pass> 
# / was on /dev/sdb4 during installation 
UUID=41dc0ef2-12f2-40dd-8082-689bb5728e95 / ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1 
# swap was on /dev/sdb5 during installation 
UUID=e191a70a-af71-44a0-9aaa-f5bb464a2233 none swap sw 0 0 
/dev/disk/by-uuid/A80E6A3A0E6A0224 
/mnt/A80E6A3A0E6A0224 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,remove_hiberfile 0 0
```

[image: sda on disk utility]
[image: sdb on disk utility]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this entire conversation and all related comments have been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51315/discussion-on-question-by-fredy-wijaya-mount-existing-2-partition-windows-from-6).